# using Virtualmin migrate sites on DigitalOcean to new vps but always return 403 forbid

Tags: apache2, vps, virtualmin

/etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost

 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
 ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
 ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

 # 138.xx.xx.xx is my server ip
 138.xx.xx.xx mydomain.com
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1003" "#1003"
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mail.mydomain.com
ServerAlias webmail.mydomain.com
ServerAlias admin.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/mydomain/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.2
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php7.2
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mydomain/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
php_admin_value engine Off
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "mydomain.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
Alias /dav /home/mydomain/public_html
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "mydomain.com"
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 138.68.92.84:443>
SuexecUserGroup "#1003" "#1003"
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
ServerAlias mail.mydomain.com
ServerAlias webmail.mydomain.com
ServerAlias admin.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/mydomain/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/mydomain/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.2
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/fcgi-bin/php7.2.fcgi .php7.2
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mydomain/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mydomain.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
php_admin_value engine Off
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "mydomain.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
Alias /dav /home/mydomain/public_html
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "mydomain.com"
AuthUserFile /home/mydomain/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php7.2
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/mydomain/ssl.cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/mydomain/ssl.key
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
</VirtualHost>
```

I hide the web behind Cloudflare

[image]

then restart Apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

I access mydomain.com, it displays

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

Your comment welcome

Comment: Make sure that the `/home/mydomain/public_html` directory has the correct permissions:
`chown -R www-data:www-data /home/mydomain/public_html/ &&
chmod 755 /home/mydomain/public_html`

Comment: @ RoseHosting thanks, I did, same result 403 Forbidden